# Is XP only awarded to the PC that delivers the killing blow?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points

I have been a DM for 35 years, and now we are embarking on 5th ed. I am playing a 1st level Barbarian. Due to Ideals and Bonds and stuff, I am letting other party members get the “kill” on stuff I have done basically all the damage to. The DM is only awarding XP to the final “kill shot” which means I am no XP. That would be fine if he was awarding me Inspiration, but he’s not...

Is there any guidance for DMs that I can show him that says I should get some of the XP for doing most of the damage to an opponent?

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)! We're happy to have you join our community!

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, I'm curious, did you know before making the character that the GM awarded exp for the killing blow? Did the Gm warn you about it when you showed up with the character? How combat heavy is the campaign so far?

Comment: More details on the Ideals/bonds may be useful to get an idea of how to tackle the situation in-game.

Comment: Seems a bit unjust - XP is supposed to mean "eXperience Points" - he is implying that your character gained no experience in fighting despite doing most of the damage, simply because he didn't deliver the final blow!

Comment: @colmde There are some games where that is a feature.  The term "kill steal" is related to it.